# node.js express jsonp return typeof

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jsonp

don't know why but my Express app is returning something weird with res.jsonp, something llike this:

```
/**/ typeof jsonp1406719695757 === 'function' && jsonp1406719695757({"published":true,"can_add_to_cart":true,"updated_at":"2014-01-[...snip...]
```

instead only this:

```
jsonp1406719695757({"published":true,"can_add_to_cart":true,"updated_at":"2014-01-[...snip...]
```

I can't understand why. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like it just verifies that there is a jsonp callback-function called `jsonp1406719695757` before calling it

Comment: Add the function that returns this value, we can't guess your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code for `res.jsonp()`, you'll find [comments](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/f34944c539f3a8e0f35a7f41011635e40141fc3c/lib/response.js#L296-L298) explaining the extra content at the beginning:

```
// the /**/ is a specific security mitigation for "Rosetta Flash JSONP abuse"
// the typeof check is just to reduce client error noise
body = '/**/ typeof ' + callback + ' === \'function\' && ' + callback + '(' + body + ');';
```

Comment: oh well, that's right and I found it works fine also with that strings, there was a problem with CORS domain and redirects. Thanks!